# angularjs: create directive inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a parent and child directive. For some reason I can't pass information from the parent to the child. This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NQgwQ/3/) demonstrates the issue I have.

The idea is as follows, the template of the parent directive looks like

```
<div>{{abc}}: <child msg="msg"></child></div>
```

As you can see, here I try to pass the msg value from the parent scope to the child, which should render the message, but inside the child directive this value is 'undefined.

Any suggestions how this can be fixed?

Comment: Your question seems cut-off prematurely. Could you add what seems to be missing at the end?

Comment: sorry, I fixed it (I was almost there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading 2 AngularJS frameworks. You can remove the external `angular.js` you added in the fiddle.

This is the updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4gusp/

Comment: Nope, it is the replace property.

Comment: @baba Nope, just follow my answer and try.

Comment: Nope, my fiddle works, I followed your example, it doesn't work. So, nope.

Comment: @baba Updated the my answer with the fiddle.

Comment: Updated your fiddle with version 1.03. http://jsfiddle.net/4gusp/1/ Still works. So no bug in angular.

Comment: I see that your jsfiddle is working, but I'm using AngularJS 1.1.1 too. What is the difference ?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri updated. you are loading 2 angular frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NQgwQ/5/

Basically I removed the replace prop:

```
replace: true -> replace:false
```

Comment: This is due to a bug, try it with newer lib. This answer doesn't make any sense. There is nothing to do with "replace".

Comment: Look at my fiddle. Does it work? It does. Here is a fiddle with what YOU suggested: http://jsfiddle.net/NQgwQ/9/

Comment: @baby You are trying to fix something based on wrong thing. This is horrible.

Comment: @sza My fiddle works, you haven't provided a fiddle. Therefore, I am right.

Comment: @sza Besides, in the OP example fiddle, the angular version is already 1.1.1

Comment: You really don't understand what I explained. Go read it. Remove the angular.js from the externalr resources. That one is 1.0.3 and conflict with the 1.1.1.

Comment: I was indeed loading two angularjs files. Stupid. But how did you know it could be fixed with 'replace' ?

Comment: Well, replace would replace the parent directive's code with the child's template, and then the msg thing wouldn't be exposed for the child to use. Basically through the replace you'd be cutting the link between the Controller and the child.